# Java Multithreading doesn't seem to be correctly working

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class which processes something. I'm trying to run a number of instances of this class in parallel.

However, I'm not sure if in `TaskManager.startAll()`, when I call `r.go()`, whether this would cause r to start running in its own thread, or within the main thread?

The total execution time that I'm getting seems to be very high, and despite my attempts at optimizing, nothing seems to be having any effect. Also, if I run a profiler on my project in Netbeans, it shows all the threads as sleeping. So I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong?

This is the structure of the class:

```
public class TaskRunner implements Runnable {
   private boolean isRunning = false;
   public void run() {
        while(true) {
            while (! running) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            process();
        }
    }

    public void go() {
       isRunning = true;
    }

    public void stop() {
       isRunning = false;
    }

    private void process() {
       //Do some number crunching and processing here
    }
}
```

Here's how these are being run / managed:

```
public class TaskManager {
     private ArrayList<TaskRunner> runners = new ArrayList<>();
     public TaskManager() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TaskRunner r = new TaskRunner();
            new Thread(r).start();
            runners.add(r);
        }
     }

     public void startAll() {
        for (TaskRunner r : runners) {
           r.go();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You have 11 Threads here. One for the `main` and 10 that started with `TaskRunner` instance as a `Runnable`.

Comment: Actually it is 11 Threads, since there are 10 TaskRunner started. However, it's not clear what you actually want to achieve and what you think your problem might be and what you have tried to solve that. There are actually quite a few issues with your code and solving them depends on what you want, so please be more specific.

Comment: @Stephan Right, skipped the loop.

Comment: @Stephan All I want to know is, when I call `r.go()` from `TaskManager.startAll()`, will this cause `r` to process things from within its own thread, or within `TaskManager`'s thread? I want all 10 threads running `TaskRunner` to be processing in parallel

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information about what the threads actually do. In this case, you're just going to get 10 threads looping forever, and sleeping. They will all run in their separate threads, yes

Comment: But Netbeans profiler shows the threads as sleeping.

Comment: Maybe because `Thread.sleep(1);`?

Comment: @Cruncher What they do doesn't seem relavant, all I want to know is how I can get each thread to process things from within its own thread and not from `TaskManager`'s thread when I call `r.go()`

Comment: @Cruncher But when I'm calling `r.go()`, I want it to break out of sleep and process things in its own thread.

Comment: @user2838678 Each `TaskRunner` here is running in its separate `Thread`. Are you saying you want tasks inside the `TaskRunner` to also be running in further separate `Thread`s?

Comment: @user2838678 I misread this all a little bit. I see what you want. your process method will all run in different threads, yes

Comment: It is still going to infinite loop on `process()`. Maybe you don't want the outer while(true) loop?

Comment: You also may want to read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html. Thread Pools are better than this approach.

Comment: And please also read about proper synchronization instead of these hot spinning loops. They give me the hibbie jibbies...

Comment: @Cruncher I don't mind it infinite looping on process.. i.e processing again each time it finishes processing one batch. I just want it to do it in its own thread and not share the main thread.

Comment: @nIcEcOw nowhere except in the while loop as I showed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you are not "doing it right." If you want to create a multi-threaded Java application, the place to start is with the `java.util.concurrent` package.

It appears from your code that you want to run ten tasks in parallel. I assume that after "number crunching and processing," you'll want to aggregate the results and do something with them in the main thread. For this, the `invokeAll()` method of `ExecutorService` works well.

First, implement `Callable` to do the work you show in your `process()` method.

```
final class YourTask implements Callable<YourResults> {

  private final YourInput input;

  YourTask(YourInput input) {
    this.input = input;
  }

  @Override
  public YourResults call() 
    throws Exception 
  {
    /* Do some number crunching and processing here. */
    return new YourResults(...);
  }

}
```

Then create your tasks and run them. This would take the place of your `main()` method:

```
Collection<Callable<YourResults>> tasks = new List<>(inputs.size());
for (YourInput i : inputs) 
  tasks.add(new YourTask(i));
ExecutorService workers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
/* The next call blocks while the worker threads complete all tasks. */
List<Future<YourResult>> results = workers.invokeAll(tasks);
workers.shutdown();
for (Future<YourResult> f : results) {
  YourResult r = f.get();
  /* Do whatever it is you do with the results. */
  ...
}
```

Comment: Say I run the 10 threads in this way once, and then they were shutdown, and later I needed to call them again, could I just do invokeAll on them again? Will this have the overhead of creating / starting the threads repeatedly? What I'm doing is, those 10 threads have to be run every second, their input received, then run again.

Comment: If you shutdown the executor, it's dead and can't be reused. You should shut them down before you lose a reference to them, because its running worker threads can't be garbage collected, and you are likely to have an effective leak. However, if you can maintain a reference to the same executor, and reuse it throughout the life of your application, you don't need to shut it down until you are ready for your program to exit.

Answer (score 3):

> However, I'm not sure if in TaskManager.startAll(), when I call r.go(), whether this would cause r to start running in its own thread, or within the main thread?

So my first comment is that you should make `isRunning` be `volatile` since it is being shared between threads.  If the threads are not starting when it goes to true (or seem to be delayed in starting) then I suspect that's your problem.  `volatile` provides memory synchronization between the threads so the thread that calls `go()` and makes a change to `isRunning` will be seen immediately by the thread waiting for the change.

Instead of spinning like this, I would use wait/notify:

```
// this synchronizes on the instance of `TaskRunner`
synchronized (this) {
   // always do your wait in a while loop to protect against spurious wakeups
   while (!isRunning && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      try {
          // wait until the notify is called on this object
          this.wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
```

Then in the `go()` method you should do the following.  `stop()` would be similar.

```
public void go() {
    synchronized (this) {
       isRunning = true;
       this.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Notice that you should handle thread interrupts carefully.  Test for `isInterrupted()` in the while running loop and re-interrupt a thread when `InterruptedException` is thrown is always a good pattern.

> The total execution time that I'm getting seems to be very high, and despite my attempts at optimizing, nothing seems to be having any effect. Also, if I run a profiler on my project in Netbeans, it shows all the threads as sleeping.

So although the threads are mostly sleeping, they are still each looping 1000 times a second because of your `Thread.sleep(1)`.  If you increased the time sleeping (after making `isRunning` be `volatile`) they would loop less but the right mechanism is to use the wait/notify to signal the thread.

Comment: Well, I have 10 instances of the Runnable taskRunner, and each has its own copy of the `isRunning`, so its not being shared outside of the instance itself. And when I call `r.go()`, processing does start as expected. Only, it takes much longer than I expect, and if I run the Profiler in netbeans, it shows all threads as sleeping even while I expected them to be running.

Comment: It is being shared outside of the instance @user2838678 since another thread is calling `startAll()` and then `go()`.  You need to have it be `volatile` at least.  Using wait/notify means that you don't need to spin and the threads should start instantaneously.

Comment: But each thread has its own `isRunning` and its only being called once to start it, then it isn't being called again

Comment: Doesn't matter @user2838678.  The thread is reading from a field which might be cached in its CPU memory cache.  If _another_ thread sets the `isRunning` field, it should be `volatile` to ensure memory synchronization.

Comment: Here are the docs on why `volatile` is necessary.  Memory inconsistency: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html   Use of `volatile`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: All right, thanks. I'll try that.. One question. If I simply made the `go()` method of TaskRunner synchronized, will that achieve the same result?

Comment: Both the _read_ and the _write_ need to either be `synchronized` or `volatile`.  `volatile` is easier @user2838678.

Answer (score 2):

Awful solution, terrible. first I highly recommend you start reading some tutorial like [[this]](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html)
Second, if threads should wait for a signal to go for some job, so why just don't you wait them!!!!!, something like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class TaskManager
{
     //////////////////////
     public volatile static Signal wait=new Signal();
     ////////////////////// 
     private ArrayList<TaskRunner> runners = new ArrayList<>();
     public TaskManager()
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TaskRunner r = new TaskRunner();
            new Thread(r).start();
            runners.add(r);
        }
        try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        startAll();
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        pauseAll();
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        startAll();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        haltAll();System.out.println("DONE!");
        }catch(Exception ex){}
     }

     public void startAll()
     {
         synchronized(wait){
                wait.setRun(true);;
                wait.notifyAll();
         }
     }
     public void pauseAll(){
     wait.setRun(false);
     }
     public void haltAll(){
      for(TaskRunner tx:runners){tx.halt();}
      }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      new TaskManager();
    }
}

class TaskRunner implements Runnable
{
   private Thread thisThread;
   private volatile boolean run=true;
   public void run()
    {
        thisThread=Thread.currentThread();
        while(run){
        if(!TaskManager.wait.isRun()){
        synchronized(TaskManager.wait)
        {
             if(!TaskManager.wait.isRun()){
               System.out.println("Wait!...");
                try
                {
                  TaskManager.wait.wait();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
             }
        }}
         process();
     }
    }
    private double r=Math.random();
    private void process(){System.out.println(r);try {
      Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
    }}
    public void halt(){run=false;thisThread.interrupt();}
}
class Signal{
  private boolean run=false;

  public boolean isRun() {
    return run;
  }

  public void setRun(boolean run) {
    this.run = run;
  }

}
```

in above sample, all runners works till the Signal run boolean is true, and simple TaskManager class set tit as false for every time it needs to pause the threads. and about the halt, it just set the shutdown(run) flag to false, and also interrupt the thread because of if thread is in wait state.

I hope I could prove your solution is like dream-on story, and also could explained enough about my solution.
have a good parallel application :)

Comment: I really don't see what the advantage of this method is

Comment: so how do you see your solution is better?! killing the CPU for sleeping and switching context and checking a variable each 1 ms?!

Comment: So what..? The CPU would be idle anyway

Comment: C'mon, just imagine what each thread is doing, each thread sleeps for 1 ms and after that checks a boolean variable, if there is no any delay, so CPU is checking a variable in memory 1000 times in one second. so do you still think CPU is idle? have you monitor your system?!