# How can I pause a loop?

Tags: java

I am making a game where the user can get a "job", and there total money increases by their salary, it pauses for a second, and then it repeats. It'll be like the cookie system in Cookie Clicker, where you make some cookies, it pauses, and then more show up. In the game, you click a button and you get a "job".

```
//The button to get a job
                    JButton workButton = new JButton("Get a job");
                    mainLayout.gridx = -1;
                    mainLayout.gridy = 1;
                    mainPanel.add(workButton, mainLayout); 
                    workButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                            boolean jobButtonClicked = true;
                            Random jobGenerator = new Random();
                            int jobSalary = jobGenerator.nextInt(200);
                            workLabel.setText("You are making $" +jobSalary);
                            int totalMoney = 0;

                            for(jobButtonClicked = true;;){

                                totalMoney = totalMoney + jobSalary;
                                //I want the total Money to increase by jobSalary, 
                                //pause for one second, and then do it again.

                            }


                        }

                });
```

I want the pause to happen here:

```
for(jobButtonClicked = true;;){

                            totalMoney = totalMoney + jobSalary;
                            //I want the total Money to increase by jobSalary, 
                            //pause for one second, and then do it again.
```

I tried "Thread.sleep();", but I get the error "The method sleep(long) in the type Thread is not applicable for the arguments ()" if I don't fill in the parameter. If I put the number of milliseconds in the parentheses I get the error: "Unhandled exception type InterruptedException" I am a beginner with this stuff, and I am doing this to learn. Please help if you can. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't just want to keep incrementing jobSalary forever. ;) Don't you want to update the label?  Also, run your loop in a different thread or else as soon as you click the button, it will block the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) and your GUI will never repaint.

Comment: Do you know any thing about [threads!](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html). [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144012/java-multithreading-doesnt-seem-to-be-correctly-working/19144771#19144771) would help too.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e){}
```

Don't forget to make a new thread for your loop.  It's not good to use the Event Dispatch Thread for stuff that sleeps, because it makes your application freeze.

Comment: `catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}` is a good practice for signaling that you deliberately want to do nothing in the `catch` block.